# How to automatically open the linux terminal window in a certain position on ubuntu

Tags: bash, gnome-terminal, 20.10, bashrc

Firstly, I know there are a few similar questions to mine at the moment; I've already checked them but did not really find a solution.

I saw this line very often: `gnome-terminal --geometry 30x30+100+0`, and yes, it almost does what I want, **BUT**, here's the point: This command **OPENS A NEW WINDOW** with the specified size, and I put it on my .bashrc and blew everything up by getting infinitely-opening terminal windows... whoops :D

Here's my question, how can I get the terminal position open as I like every time I press the terminal icon or try to open it with any shortcut possible PERMANENTLY (of course without having to deal with an infinite loop)?
Am I supposed to type something in a certain path?

I'm using the latest version of ubuntu (20.10).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can assign a keyboard shortcut in your settings. When you're assigning a shortcut it'll ask for a command to execute every time the shortcut is pressed. There you can set the command as gnome-terminal with --geometry option set

Comment: True, but this basically works only if I press the binding keys, not when I click on the Terminal icon, right?

Comment: Yes unfortunately. But I don't almost remember myself clicking on terminal icon at all. I usually open it through a shortcut, especially if it's an easy shortcut like ctrl+enter. I'll let you know if something better comes to my mind

Comment: Thanks! I also love shortcuts; the reason I said such a thing was that I was wondering if there's a way to basically change the position of the terminal window to a specific x and y no matter from what way you open it (whether key bindings or by clicking on the icon). Your solution is cool though ;)

Comment: You're very welcome. I'd appreciate if you marked the question solved if I answered to what you were looking for :) Have a nice day

Answer (score 0):

Put that `-geometry ...` parameter into the .desktop file, not into your .bashrc. Copy the original terminal .desktop file to a new one where you can do that, and give it a keyboard shortcut.

Comment: The idea is good, but I do not know if the user will be able to proceed with this very sparse explanation. For one, you can not easily bind a hotkey to a `.desktop` file and, two, it is not quite elegant to have two Terminal icons in the overview if you copy the `.desktop` file.